# Visual Studio: Find / Replace using regular expression to replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the Find / Replace tool of visual studio to find something using regular expressions and make a replace. I have this in the find: `Assert.IsTrue\(([^,;]*)\) *;` and the replace `Assert.IsTrue($1, "$1");`, so what this does is looking for every `Assert.IsTrue();` whith anything in the parentheses except for commas `,` and semicolons `;`, and then add whatever was on the parentheses inside quotes and after a comma `,`. So, if I have `Assert.IsTrue(wtv)` it will be replaced with `Assert.IsTrue(wtv,"wtv")`.

The problem is when the `wtv` has quotes or break lines, so if I have

`Assert.IsTrue("wtv" == "wtv")` it will be replaced to

`Assert.IsTrue("wtv" == "wtv", ""wtv" == "wtv"")` and

```
Assert.IsTrue(wtv ||
wtv2)
```

will be replaced to

```
Assert.IsTrue(wtv ||
wtv2, "wtv ||
wtv2")
```

. What I want to do is eliminate **in the replacement** the new line \r and the quotes, so the results after the replacement are

`Assert.IsTrue("wtv" == "wtv", "wtv == wtv")` and

```
Assert.IsTrue(wtv ||
    wtv2, "wtv ||wtv2")
```

Comment: I would write a console application which would do the same with regular expressions instead trying to use the limited VS Regex.

Comment: @OmegaMan at the end this is what will be done, I was exploring several possibilities and was curious for the question. Thanks

Comment: I love regex, don't get me wrong; just that multiple line crossings are difficult enough to handle in regex (usually used by a negative look ahead), but near impossible in VS interpretation of the pattern. :-) It doesn't hurt to ask and to that your post is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll clarify that this doesn't really solve the problem, is just a **nasty** work around, not a real solution. I post it just in case someone needs a work around as I do (I doubt it but well). Still, as this is not the real answer I'll not mark it as so (unless someone explains me that it's not possible a real answer), and new answers are always welcomed.

What I did was in the part that need regex add several groups that `([^,;"\r\n]*)` first look for anything that it's not a comma, semicolon, quote or new-line, then look for `(["\r\n]*)` ne-line or semicolon, and then repeat this pattern several times.

So, what this will do as it's using `*` it will look if it happens 0 or more times, and is repeated several times in case that there is more than one comma or more than one new-line (note that if there are none, that's not a problem since I'm using `*`). And, the replace would look like

```
Assert.IsTrue($1$2$3..., "$1$3$5...");
```

where in the first argument I put all the numbers, and in quotes I put only the odd numbers since the even are either non existent or quote / new-line.

I used 31 of these, so if there are more than 15 groups of commas / new-line, it will not be found and replaced
The find

```
Assert.IsTrue\(([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)(["\r\n]*)([^,;"\r\n]*)\) *;
```

The replace

```
Assert.IsTrue($1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16$17$18$19$20$21$22$23$24$25$26$27$28$29$30$31, "$1$3$5$7$9$11$13$15$17$19$21$23$25$27$29$31");
```

This works for the examples I provided and for any example with less than 15 groups of commas / new-lines, if I can come up with something better (since this a really crappy solution), I'll add it here.

Comment: Note that this will be much slower, the more capturing groups you add, the slower it will be.